# python variable concatination with different equators

Tags: python

How would I be able to make a variable that contains another = sign in it, like this:

```
newval = dict[key_to_find] = int(change)
```

Comment: I don't understand your example.  Variable names can't contain equal signs.  Your example looks like assigning the value `int(change)` to two targets, `newval` and `dict[key_to_find]`.

Comment: Do you want a boolean, such that `newval` is either `True` or `False`? In that case you need a double equal sign, `newval = 1 == 1`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm trying to assign the change of a dictionary value to the variable newval

Comment: @DannyBolland: What is "the change of a dictionary value"?  What do you expect the value of `newval` to be after this occurs?

Comment: @BrenBarn You know how you have a value assigned to a key in a dictionary, I'm trying to change the value of the key "key_to_find" to int(change) and set it into the variable Newval.

Comment: @DannyBolland: If I understand right, your code will already do that.  That is, after you run that line, both `newval` and `dict[key_to_find]` will be set to `int(change)`.  But that is not setting `newval` to a "change".  It's just setting `newval` to the same thing you're setting `dict[key_to_find]` to .  It would help if you could include a complete example with sample input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with doing this is that in Python the '=' is an assignment operator rather than a symbol.

Python is reading what you wrote as trying to assign to two variables. For example:

`foo = "test"` and `bar = "test"` can be written as `foo = bar = "test"`

**Creating a variable name with an '=' it can't be done.**

If you are trying to create a new variable that has a string value that comes from two other sources you can use the format that intboolstring suggested, or the `format` function is pretty handy.

Going along with your example:

`newval = "{dict} = {int}".format(dict=dict[key_to_find], int = int(change))`

To give a simpler example of how this works:

`var_a = 'Hello'
var_b = 'world'
variable = "{a} {b}!".format(a = var_a, b = var_b)`

Variable will print:

> "Hello world!"

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing the answer off of

> variable that **contains** another = sign in it

I think you are trying to concatenate `dict[key_to_find]` and `int(change)` with an equal sign in the middle.  This can be done with the following

```
newval = str(dict[key_to_find]) + " = " + str(int(change))
```

The reason that I'm leaving in the `int` cast is because if you had change as `7.5`, then you would want it in the string as `7`.